# PHP Make Directory

Tags: php, directory

I am not sure why this code is breaking

```
mkdir("upload/".$username.'/'.$title.'/', 0700);
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/".$username.'/'.$title.'/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " ."upload/".$username.'/'.$title.'/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      $link = "upload/".$username.'/'.$title.'/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Here are my errors

Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in /Volumes/shared/Digital/_Websites/_TEST/qpm/submit.php on line 101

Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/test/test/Hand Over.docx) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Volumes/shared/Digital/_Websites/_TEST/qpm/submit.php on line 103

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpYvo5b5' to 'upload/test/test/Hand Over.docx' in /Volumes/shared/Digital/_Websites/_TEST/qpm/submit.php on line 103
Stored in: upload/test/test/Hand Over.docx1 record added

I;m sure i had this working and now I have somehow broke it?

the echo stored in echos the correct string so not sure why the mkdir is failing, apologies if this a simple fix

Comment: Use absolute paths for file functions.

Comment: Don't use `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` to create files on your system.

Comment: `mkdir()` has 3rd parameter called `$recursive`. Set it to `true` if you are generating multilevel directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you should know about `mkdir()`:

1. By default, it can only create a directory if the parent directory exists; it can create intermediate directories if you pass `true` as the third parameter.
2. Without an absolute path, it's hard to say where your directory will get created. You can either use a configuration file to store this or use a combination of `__FILE__`, `__DIR__` and `dirname()` to derive it.

I would further advice never to use the value of `$_FILES['file']['name']` directly to create files on your server; use [`tempnam()`](http://php.net/tempnam), optionally in combination with a sanitized version of the original file name.

Answer (score 0):

first it is strongly recommended to use absolute path instead of relative path.because relative path may not be working well if you run this php script in an other path.
take this for eg:

> test.php:
> /home/donald/test.php

```
<?php
    mkdir("test_dir");
```

when pwd is "/home/donald/" you run "php test.php" it will make a "test_dir" in /home/donald/

when pwd is "/home/" you run "php donald/test.php"  it will a make "test_dir" in /home/
and you can also add true to mkdir() as the 3rd param to mkdir recursively or just use "exec('mkdir -p yourpath')" if it's allowed